# Windows Authentication for remote reporting services

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, reporting-services, single-sign-on

I have a ASP.NET web application that I use to display MS reports using a Report Viewer.
The reports are sitting on a remote server. I need to use windows authentication to connect to the reporting services, as I need to display the reports based on who is logged on the web application.

I've searched on the net for a solution,but couldn't find anything.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually facing a similar issue right now.  You need to configure the web server for DELEGATION.

The issue is that your web server can authenticate people locally using their windows credentials, but even if it impersonates these users their credentials aren't, by default, usable on the network.  You have to configure ActiveDirectory to recognize the web server as having the authority to impersonate a user on the local network.

Here are some links to get you started (I'm currently reading these which is why I have them open!):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810572/
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907272
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx